# Greatest common divisor in a custom assembler

Tags: assembly

I am currently studying computer architecture, and we got the task of writing the code of the Greatest Common Divisor with these assembler rules:

```
## Assembler
| # | Mnemonics              | Action                       |
| - | ---------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| 0 | `AND Ra, Rb`           | `Ra &= Rb`                   |
| 1 | `OR Ra, Rb`            | `Ra \= Rb`                   |
| 2 | `ADD Ra, Rb`           | `Ra += Rb`                   |
| 3 | `SUB Ra, Rb`           | `Ra -= Rb`                   |
| 4 | `LW Ra, (Rb)`          | `Ra = Mem[Rb]`               |
| 5 | `SW Ra, (Rb)`          | `Mem[Rb] = Ra`               |
| 6 | `MOV Ra, Rb`           | `Ra = Rb`                    |
| 7 | `INP Ra`               | `Ra = Inp`                   |
| 8 | `JEQ Ra, value\label` | `PC = value\label, Ra == 0`   |
| 9 | `JNE Ra, value\label` | `PC = value\label, Ra != 0`   |
| a | `JGT Ra, value\label` | `PC = value\label, Ra > 0`    |
| b | `JLT Ra, value\label` | `PC = value\label, Ra < 0`    |
| c | `LW Ra, value\label`  | `Ra = Mem[value\label]`       |
| d | `SW Ra, value\label`  | `Mem[value\label] = Ra`       |
| e | `LI Ra, value\label`  | `Ra = value\label`            |
| f | `JMP value\label`     | `PC = value\label`            |

## Registers
| ## | Name | Description                   |
| -- | ---- | ----------------------------- |
| 00 | R0   | User data                     |
| 01 | R1   | User data                     |
| 10 | R2   | User data (output pins A0-A7) |
| 11 | R3   | User data (output pins B0-B7) |
```

So far I have written this:

```
    LI R3, 0x00
    LI R2, 0x00
    LI R1, 0x1d #R1 and R0 are the two numbers. 
    LI R0, 0x07

    MOV R2, R0
    MOV R3, R1
loop:
    SUB R3, R0  #R3 = 3
    JGT R3, aloop   #if R3 > 0 then go to aloop
    JLT R3, bloop   #if R3 < 0 then go to bloop
    JEQ R3, cloop   #if R3 == 0 then go to ertek
aloop:

    MOV R1, R3  #R1 = 3

    JMP loop

bloop:

    ADD R0, R3
    MOV R3, R0

    JMP loop
cloop:

    MOV R3, R0
    JMP end

end:

    JMP end
```

My problem is that I cannot make the code universal. So it works for instance to R1 = 9 and R0 = 6, but only that. The names "loop", "bloop", "cloop" could be understood as `goto 'name'` in C.

Comment: You should instead give an example that does not work. Then follow the steps of your code, either in your head, on paper or a debugger and see why it doesn't work. That said, `MOV R3, R0`  in `bloop` looks suspicious because it sets `R3 = R0` so the loop terminates immediately.

Comment: What's the point of `MOV R1, R3` after label `aloop:`?

Comment: I was wondering why turning R3 into R0 if R3 is 0? For the answer, I assumed it R3 right? Have you try your code with for example (12 and 4, 5 and 7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code, I get the greatest common divisor using Euclid's algorithm. Of which, you can check it out from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor. The Euclid's algorithm may or may not be the most efficient algorithm. Nonetheless, I though it is the most easiest to understand when putting into code.

The code is pretty much self explanatory because of the amount of comments in the code.

Thanks tibiv111 for letting me know that ADD can only be done with registers and not values. Thus, and because Euclid's algorithm does not require quotient values, I updated the answer code to not keep track of the quotient value.

```
    LI R3, 0x00       # R3 is used to return an answer.
    LI R2, 0x00       
    LI R1, 0x1d       # R1 and R0 are the two numbers.
    LI R0, 0x07       # R0 = first number, R1 = second number.

    JEQ R0, niszero   # R0 == 0, one number is zero.
    JEQ R1, niszero   # R1 == 0, one number is zero.

    MOV R2, R0        # Move first number into R2.
    SUB R2, R1        # Subtract first number to second number.

    JEQ R2, nequal    # R2 == 0, two numbers are equal.
    JMP divide        # Jump to divide. Remember if there is change
                      #  to code then R3 must be set 0 before going into
                      #  divide.

nequal:               # Two numbers are equal.
    MOV R3, R0        # When two numbers are equal
                      #  either one of them could be
                      #  the greatest common divisor
    JMP end           # Jump to end.

niszero:              # Either one of the numbers is a 0.
    MOV R3, 0         # In this case, I just set the return register
                      #  to zero, or give back an answer of zero.
    JMP end           # Jump to end.         

divide:     
                      # R0 is 1st number.
                      # R1 is 2nd number.
                      # R3 is remainder (Have to be set 0 before send here).
                      # Quotient isn't needed to be calculate as
                      #  GCD calculation by Euclid's algorithm does
                      #  not require quotient values.

    SUB R0, R1        # Subtract R0 to R1.

    JGT R0, divide    # If R0 > 0 then continue substracting.
    JLT R0, div_wr    # If R0 < 0 then division is done with remainder.
    JEQ R0, loop      # If R0 == 0 then division is done without remainder.

div_wr:               # Division is done with remainder.
    ADD R0, R1        # To get the remainder, add R0 back to R1,
    MOV R3, R0        #  then assign that value to R3.
    JMP loop          # Jump back to loop.

loop:
    JEQ R3, loop_d    # If R3(remainder) == 0 we are done.

    MOV R0, R1        # Else R0(first divisor) become R1.
    MOV R1, R3        # R1 become remainder.
    MOV R3, 0         # Set R3 to 0.
    JMP divide        # continue dividing.

loop_d:               # loop is done
    MOV R3, R1        # If remainder is 0
                      #  then R1 is the answer.
                      # However, I assumed R3 is the return register
                      #  so copy R1 to R3.
    JMP end           # Jump to end

end:
    JMP end
```

Comment: The only problem with the code is you cannot add a value to a register alone. For instance 'ADD R2, 1' is not correct. It should somehow look like this: ADD R2, R0. But since R0 is taken or many times not 1, it cannot really be used. Otherwise amazing. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @tibiv111 - Oh, I did not notice that. :D. Nonetheless, you don't need to keep track of the quotient. Thus, you don't need the ADD to 1 code. Would you like me to update the code with the fix?

Comment: Would you be so kind to do that? :)

Comment: @tibiv111 - I already did that. Check out the new code. Hope you like it.